# How to access complex structured data in swift?

Tags: swift

```
struct SubSection {
    let title:String
    var options: [SubSettingsOptionType]
}

enum SubSettingsOptionType {
    case staticCell(model:SubSettingsOption)
    case switchCell(model:SubSettingsSwitchOption)
}

class SubSettingsSwitchOption {
    let title:String
    let handler: (() -> Void)
    let isOn:Bool
    
    init(title:String, _ mHandler:@escaping (() -> Void), isOn:Bool) {
        self.title = title
        self.isOn = isOn
        self.handler = mHandler
    }
}

class SubSettingsOption {
    var title:String
    var isSelected:Bool
    var handler: ((Int, Int) -> Void)
    
    init(title:String, isSelected:Bool, _ mHandler:@escaping ((Int, Int) -> Void)) {
        self.title = title
        self.isSelected = isSelected
        self.handler = mHandler
    }
}
```

I came across a code with a complex structure for me as above
When I try to access and use this code, I am using the following, but it is very inconvenient every time I use it.
Is there an easier way to access the data?

```
let type = models[0].options[0]
switch type.self {
case .staticCell(let model):
    model.isSelected = true
case .switchCell(let model):
    model.handler()
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what is inconvenient? I can understand that using this code structure can be a bit messy but it’s not so easy to give some suggestions either because it depends on the use case.

Answer (score 2):

If you're stuck with the `enum`, the `switch` is probably the most convenient method of doing different things for the various cases.  `if` also supports patterns that can match the cases of an `enum`, but that's rarely more convenient than a `switch`, and is usually noticeably more awkward, not to mention that `if` can't enforce that you handled all cases of an `enum`.

But that doesn't mean you have to litter your code with `switch` statements.  If what you're doing in the various cases is consistent, extract that into a function, for example create an `extension` on `SubSettingsOptionType` in which this function would be a method in that `extension`, and then just use that function instead of a `switch` every time.

I'll give you an example, but keep in mind I don't really know anything about the context of your code, so the names I give things almost certainly can be much better.

```swift
extension SubSettingsOptionType 
{
    func apply()
    {
        switch self
        {
            case .staticCell(let model):
                model.isSelected = true

            case .switchCell(let model):
                model.handler()
        }
    }
}
```

With that in place, the code you find inconvenient can be reduced to:

```swift
models[0].options[0].apply()
```

You may have several sets of use cases that come up repeatedly in your code, so you may end up with several such functions, each to handle one of the consistent sets.  If you name the function(s) well, your code will be easier to read too.

Another approach might be to imagine how you'd design it in a more convenient way if you were free to replace the `enum` with something else, then write a set of adapters that wrap the `enum`, but provide the API you'd prefer.

For example, maybe you'd prefer polymorphism, you might define something like:

```swift
protocol CellOptionType {
    func apply()
}

struct StaticCellOptionType: CellOptionType
{
    var model: SubSettingsOption
    func apply() { model.isSelected = true }
}

struct SwitchCellOptionType: CellOptionType
{
    var model: SubSettingsSwitchOption
    func apply() { model.handler() }
}

extension SubSettingsOptionType 
{
    var cellOptionType: CellOptionType
    {
        switch self
        {
            case .staticCell(let model):
                return StaticCellOptionType(model: model)

            case .switchCell(let model):
                return SwitchCellOptionType(model: model)
        }
    }
}
```

Now instead of your original code you can write

```swift
models[0].options[0].cellOptionType.apply()
```

or assign it to a variable to do something with it later

```swift
let cellOptionType = models[0].options[0].cellOptionType

// Some time later in your code
cellOptionType.apply()
```

Is this actually better? Maybe.  It depends on how often you need to call `apply` and how much you store/pass-around `SubSettingsOptionType` instances.

Yet another alternative is to implement a more fluid-style API in an `extension`. This can be helpful if you don't have a lot of consistent use cases and the number of `enum` cases isn't likely to grow.  Something like this:

```swift
extension SubSettingsOptionType 
{
    func onStaticCell(_ code: (_ model: SubSettingsOption) throws) rethrows -> Self?
    {
        switch self
        {
            case staticCell(let model):
                code(model)
                return nil

            default: return self
        }
    }

    func onSwitchCell(_ code: (_ model: SubSettingsSwitchOption) throws) rethrows -> Self?
    {
        switch self
        {
            case switchCell(let model):
                code(model)
                return nil

            default: return self
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```swift
models[0].options[0]
    .onStaticCell { $0.isSelected = true }
    ?.onSwitchCell { $0.handler() }
```

Although I usually like fluid API's, in this case, the need to optionally unwrap here makes it a bit more awkward.   There are ways to get around that - wrap the enum, and keep track of which `on...` methods have been called.  That would eliminate the need for the optional. I'll leave that "as an exercise" for now.